# open map equivalent definition

Tags: general-topology

$f : (X,\tau_X) \to (Y,\tau_Y) $ continuous and surjective. I need to prove that

$f$ is open  $\Longleftrightarrow \forall U\in\tau_X, f^{-1}(f(U))\in \tau_X$

Proof:

$\implies)$ By definition, $f$ is open if $\forall U\in\tau_X, f(U)\in\tau_Y$. As f is continuous, $f^{-1}(f(U))\in \tau_X$

$\Longleftarrow)$ Now we suppose $\forall U\in\tau_X, f^{-1}(f(U))\in \tau_X$

I know that $U\subseteq f^{-1}(f(U))\in \tau_X$ and the equality holds when f is injective, but I just know that f is surjetive

How can I continue?

Thank you for your help and time

Comment: There must be some hypothesis missing. What if $f $ is the identity to $ X $ with the indiscrete topology?

Comment: No, the exercise says exacly what I wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true.  Let $X$ denote the real line with the discrete topology, let $Y$ denote the real line with the usual topology, and let $f : X \to Y$ be the identity map.  Clearly $f$ is a continuous surjection, and is not an open mapping.  However $f^{-1} [ f [ U ] ] = U$ for all (open) $U \subseteq X$.